# How to solve $T(n)=\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T(i)+\Theta(n)$

Tags: proof-writing, recurrence-relations, recursion

I need to solve this Recursion Relation:$$T(n)=\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T(i)+\Theta(n)$$
Do you have any idea how?
(I try to find another way instead induction).

(We should get: $T(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$)

This might help - [From the book we should see the solution]:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$A(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} T(n)\,x^n.$$
Then:
$$\frac{A(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{m\leq n}T(n)\right) x^n,\qquad A(x)\cdot\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{m<n}T(m)\right) x^n,$$
so the recursion gives:
$$ A(x)=2\int_{0}^{x}\frac{A(t)}{1-t}\,dt+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right),$$
or:
$$ (1-x)B'(x) = 2B(x)+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right), $$
from which:
$$ B(x) = \frac{x+C}{(1-x)^2},\qquad A(x)=\frac{x+C}{(1-x)^2}$$
and $T(n)\leq (C+1) n$.

Comment: I don't understand how do you got it.... And where is the $\Theta (n \log n)$??  If you can write it more simple I'll be glad, I don't understand you proof...

Comment: If you can use what I have (the part from the book) it will be great!!

Comment: Your book just shows that if $T(n)\ll n\log n$ for any $n< N$, then $T(N)\ll N\log N$, too. This is pretty obvious. Using generating functions as I did, it is not difficult to show that the stronger bound $T(n)\ll n$ holds.

Comment: Thank you but I found how I should solve it... We should solve it in a different way! But thank you anyway!! :-)